# unable to read a string of file names from a text file

Tags: python

I am trying to make a slide show and have all of the image paths stored in 1 text file to make the main code a bit cleaner, 
here is the main code :

```
import tkinter as tk
from itertools import cycle
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

images = open('list.txt', 'r').read()
print(images)

photos = cycle(ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(image)) for image in images)

def slideShow():
  img = next(photos)
  displayCanvas.config(image=img)
  root.after(1200, slideShow) 

root = tk.Tk()
root.overrideredirect(True)
width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
height = root.winfo_screenwidth()
root.geometry('%dx%d' % (1600, 900))
displayCanvas = tk.Label(root)
displayCanvas.pack()
root.after(1000, lambda: slideShow())
root.mainloop()
```

and here is a download for the list file, in case it needs reformatting or something: https://drive.google.com/open?id=17PzCCf6DK9L-8q4ZxVe7bPD1kFlIuZts

I currently get this error when I try to run the code 
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '['`
I have tried formatting it in different ways, nothing worked it all just had whatever the first character was and then "no such file or directory"

Comment: Seems a line in your file is just `[`

Comment: its not , atleast in notepad ++ it is formatted  like this
`["example1.jpg","example2.jpg","example3.jpg"]`  just a lot longer and actual file names

Comment: And I think you are calling the file which is not in current working directory

Comment: Is there a reason you're storing a formatted list within the file instead of names on separate lines?

Comment: I think @cricket_007 raises a very good point. In any case, couldn’t you use `ast.literal_eval()` for this? You could probably parse it as JSON, too. Also, you should use context managers to handle files.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile i am very new to this kind of thing , i used the way i knew how to from previous projects, it may not be a good way , but it works.

Comment: @anytarsier67 I’m not reprimanding you, don’t worry! :) It’s just a few suggestions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string representation of list to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace

```py
images = open('list.txt', 'r').read()
print(images)
```

with

```py
images =[]
with open('list.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().strip('[]')
    images = [i.strip("\" ") for i in lines.split(',')]
```

Your text file is formatted differently. All I did is strip the text file of `[]` and then split them with `,` delimiter and then removed the trailing white spaces and the `"`.
 Hope this helps you :)

Comment: so the list.txt would be `example1.jpg,example2.jpg` and so on ?

Comment: yes. and don't worry you need not format the text file. I have written the code to adapt to your text file.

Comment: do you mean it will work with the version that i have up for download?

Comment: yes. it would work absolutely fine. I have tested it.

Comment: glad I could be of help :)

Comment: a new problem has appeared, would you be able to help me figure out why most of the images are getting cut off.

Comment: what do you mean by cut off?

Comment: i will only see a small part of the image , like most of it will be off screen , i think it is because they are all diffrent resolutions.

Comment: yeah even I think so, but I guess `tkinter` has specific functions to resolve that. You can try adjusting the resolution or try to find that specific function. I am not quite familiar with tkinter so I guess I am not the right person to advice you on this.

Comment: well guess im in for some diggin.

Comment: yeah you can create another SO question :p

Comment: This fails if any of the elements of the list contain a comma. The `r` option is redundant, since it's the default. There is also no need to escape the double quote: `i.strip("\" ")` --> `i.strip('" ')`.

Comment: the list doesn't seem to contain a `,` moreover, even if it does contain, all he gotta do is to insert a `,` in the strip function. I am also aware of the fact that `r` is redundant here but as he is a new contributor, I considered keeping it as much less confusing as possible :)

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `.read()` on the file, which loads everything to a string.

Then you're looping over the string, character by character, trying to open the character as an image

If you have names on each line, then you want this

```
with open('list.txt', 'r') as f:
    images = f.readlines()
    print(images)
    photos = cycle(ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(image.rstrip())) for image in images)
```

If your file is formatted any differently, you'll need to parse it first into a list of image file names

Comment: how would i format the list.txt for this?
would it be like 
```
example1.jpg
example2.jpg
```
or would i need symbols around it?
EDIT: i cant get the formatting right it is supposed to be the fine name and extension then right to the next line

Comment: No symbols. Just file names by themselves on each line

Comment: You can format the file any number of different ways; you just need to have code that handles the format you use.

Comment: it gave me this error `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '11385a9.jpg\n'`
that file is in the active directory, so i dont know what this means

Comment: Try `Image.open(image.rstrip()))`

Comment: sorry i am very new to this and also sleep deprived, where should i put that?

Comment: In place of the existing `Image.open()` call

Answer (score 0):

```
open('list.txt', 'r').read()
```

This reads the *entire* file as a *single* string, without heed to what that string actually looks like.

```
cycle(ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(image)) for image in images)
```

This tries to use each element of `images` for an `Image.open` call. Since `images` is a single string (produced by the previous line), its elements are the individual characters of that string (as 1-character strings). Hence `'['` as the first of them.

It seems as though you expected to write the *string representation of* a list to a file, and then get the *actual corresponding list* back automatically by reading the file. This does not work. You need to actually interpret the file contents to build the list.

Answer (score 0):

Accidently you created `JSON` file which you can convert back to Python's list with module `json`

```
import json

images = json.loads(open('list.txt').read())

print(images[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

#### 1.

```py
import json

with open('../resources/list.txt') as list_file:
    list_res = json.load(list_file)
```

#### 2.

```py
from ast import literal_eval

with open('../resources/list.txt') as list_file:
    list_res = literal_eval(list_file.read())
```